# Problemas com estouro de pilha usando a função ifelse

Tags: r

Olá, tudo bem?

Estou com dificuldades ao gerar um função com base em `ifelse()`, pois ocorre estouro de pilha acima de 49 condições. Estou tendando calcular médias a cada 5 mim. para isso preciso usar a função para fazer as "amplitudes".

exemplo de dados:

```
eval(parse(text=
  paste(c("cut.M5<-c(",rep("",287)),'"',c(rep(0,12),rep(1:23,each=12)),"H ",c(0,seq(5,55,5)),"M 0S",'"',c(rep(",",287),')'),sep=""))
  )
x=paste(rep(seq(0,24,1),each=60),"H ",1:60,"M 0S",sep="")
```

exemplo da função:

```
eval(parse(text=paste(c("tempo.5m<-function(x){",rep("",286)),'ifelse(x>=cut.M5[',1:287,'] & x<cut.M5[',2:288,'],cut.M5[',1:287,'] ',c(rep(",",286),paste(',ifelse(x>cut.m5[288],cut.m5[288],"não")',paste(rep(")",287),collapse = " "),"}",collapse = "") ),sep=""))
  )
```

Como geram mais de 49 condições... ocorre o estouro de pilha, alguém sabe outra maneira de realizar essa marcação?

Comment: Veja se `dplyr::case_when` resolve esse problema.

Comment: resolveu sim, obrigado!!!